# Atomic copy an object attributes

Tags: python, object, copy, tuples

I have an object which keeps changing with time independent of my program.

So for example, my `data` keeps getting updated after some random but small interval.

Now I wish to copy certain attributes this object at some time t. How do I make sure that my operation is atomic without copying the whole object? `data` has some other values which are not interesting to me.

Here's the code snippet:

```
def get_values(self):
        if self.data:
            return (self.data.a, self.data.b, self.data.c)
        else:
            return (0, 0, 0)
```

Here, I am only concerned about `data.a`, `data.b`, and `data.c`. I want to return these values as a tuple in get_values. Is this atomic? Does this guarantee that a, b, c values will be consistent in time? What's the best way to do this?

Comment: What are the types of a,b and c?

Comment: We can assume them to be integers for now. But can be floats as well.

Comment: If your program isn't changing the data, what entity is? Does that entity respect the GIL?

Comment: Data is being changed by a process over which I have no control and have no knowledge of.

Comment: How does exactly changes made by external process reflect the Python object? Do you read something from, say, file system on each access to `a`, `b` or `c`, or do you use shared memory?

Comment: If you actually have "no knowledge of" how `self.data` is being modified, then there is no valid answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Use locks. Multi consumer/single producer locks are fine, but mutexes will work too as proof-of-concept. Just write-lock the object before changing it, either with Python synchronization, or with some external stuff, like FS locks, and release it after updating. And consumers should read-lock the object before reading the state from it, but they can be sure it will remain consistent as long as they don't release the read-lock.

If you can't, you have options, but they are dependent on how do you modify the object.

1. If your object retrieves external data, e.g. `a`, `b` and `c` are getters reading something from the, say, file system, on each access, you have to ensure they are consistent. Make a method to read `a`, `b` and `c` at once from external source, and use it instead of property access.
2. If updating code is Python too, and it runs in the same interpreter as yours, you are both subject to GIL, unless updater uses `ctype` witchery. Python can preemptively switch your thread into something that will change your object in the middle of you wrapping it into tuple, and there is not much you can do about it. I'd take a look into how to temporarily disable preemption (e.g. force hold GIL on your thread) in this case, but this certainly won't be pure Python solution.
3. Use RCU. If `data` is the only pointer to the object being updated, you can create `data` instances beforehand, and quickly swap `self.data` reference with your own forged new instance, while keeping old `data` object alive and available for you to analyze. External process will then update new `data`. You do this in two steps:

   ```
   new_data = Data() # create data object, but it's
                     # invisible to anyone except you now

   old_data = self.data # active object captured, but can
                        # still be updated in the middle,
                        # so unsafe to use now

   self.data = new_data # done! now all changes go to
                        # new_data, and old_data is
                        # available for you to inspect it
   ```
4. If your object consists not only with `a`, `b` and `c`, but also has some heavy state expensive to copy, you can implement something similar to Javascript prototyping yourself, combined with RCU approach, and a bit of lock-free programming.

   So, you have an object, holding lockfree double-linked list of "snapshots", the topmost snapshot being your current state, each holding references to the next and the the previous state (except for those at the head and the tail of the list). You start with single snapshot, being empty object.

   Intercept writes to your object with `__setattr__`, and unconditionally update topmost state.

   In order to safely read data from your object, you have to create new empty state and append it to the end of double-linked list of snapshots, effectively redirecting all subsequent writes, while keeping previous state unchanged; and remember the reference to state snapshot that was topmost at the moment of taking a snapshot.

   Then, to read each value, you first start with remembered topmost state and look if it has the value with desired name. If it does not, descend to previous snapshot in linked list, and repeat until you either find the value, or reach the bottom. You may make this approach transparent with using `__getattr__`.

   After finishing analyzing, you may need to save memory. Do this by merging all the state snapshots from bottom to top into one single state object, append it to the list of snapshots, and clean all shadowed snapshots afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Numbers, strings, and tuples in Python are immutable; using augmented assignment will rebind the name.

Your other types are merely mutated, and remain the same object.

So it will indeed be a copy.

Comment: Despite tuple being immutable, tuple construction is not atomic. If thread switches while populating stack with arguments to `BUILD_TUPLE` (and it will some day), tuple will get half of items from "before" state, and half of items from "after" state. That's why thread synchronization was invented.

Comment: E.g. `t = (a, b, c, d)` compiles to sequence of `LOAD_FAST` and `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcodes, pushing the `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` references to the stack, and then `BUILD_TUPLE` is done, which grabs all of them and stores at the top of stack the tuple object, which is then, possibly, `STORE_FAST`ed to the variable `t`. As you may see, there is no chance tuple will become unaffected by other thread, if it decided to screw things, even in presence of GIL.

Comment: @modchan Didn't really think of threads to be honest. I am gonna leave up this answer for others to see and learn something new.